# Android Studio: Query documents containing array node using a substring

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to search **Documents** in a **Collection** which contain a certain `key`.

Here is how I structured my Firestore database:

```
-- FirestoreRoot
   |-- Products        (Collection)
      |-- Departments  (Document)
         |-- Food      (Colletion)
            |-- {Id}   (Document)
               -- description : "this is my very first description"
               -- keywords :
                  -- 0 : this
                  -- 1 : is
                  -- 2 : my
                  -- 3 : very
                  -- 4 : first
                  -- 5 : description
```

In the example below, I was able to search by using a `substring` for the first word in the `description`. To this date, this method does not work for querying the following words. In the example below, typing the letters "thi" is enough to return documents.

```
        CollectionReference colecRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Products")
                .document("Departments")
                .collection("Food");

        Query query = colecRef;
        query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("description", searchField.getText().toString().toLowerCase())
                .whereLessThan("description", searchField.getText().toString().toLowerCase()+'\uf8ff')
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(SearchActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: "+documentSnapshot);
                }
            }
        });
```

In my case, I need to search by using 1 or multiple keys, for example: **first** or **first description**. And by using the whole word or only a substring, for example: **first** or **descr**

I've tried to use `whereArrayContains()`, but I can't use it typing `multiple keys` or `substring`.

```
      query.whereArrayContains("keywords",searchField.getText().toString().toLowerCase())
                        .get().addOnSuccessListener(SearchActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: "+documentSnapshot);
                        }
                    }
                })
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: There is a little "hack" that can be made in Firestore than can help you [search the database easier](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444). Unfortunately it is not using arrays but you should take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore currently only offers two ways to query the contents of an array:

- [Array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) with [whereArrayContains()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#public-query-wherearraycontains-string-field,-object-value).  This will tell you if an element exists in an array. It must match exactly - no substrings.
- [array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) memberhip with [whereArrayContainsAny()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#public-query-wherearraycontainsany-string-field,-list-extends-object-values).  This will tell you if any of the given strings exist in the array. It must match exactly - no substrings.

As you can see, searching substrings in arrays isn't going to work at all.  You might want to consider using another database in tandem with Firestore in order to satisfy these specific queries, as Firestore is not very well suited for them.

Comment: I am using `firestore:20.0.0`, but `whereArrayContainsAny()` is not available for `Query` and `.collection("Food")
.where("keywords", "array-contains-any", ["first", "description"])` is also not available. What am I missing?

Comment: Upgrade to at least 21.3.0.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v21-3-0

Comment: Is there something close to `whereArrayContainsAny()` or `whereArrayContains()` for `Firebase Realtime Database`?